# Can I remove spaces from a property name inside a reduce function?

Tags: javascript

I came up with the following way to reduce my data:

```
data = [{ id: 99991, name: "NoData1", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99992, name: "NoData2", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99993, name: "NoData3", title: "No Data" }];


var dataMapName = data.reduce((rv, v) => {
    rv[v.name] = v;
    return rv;
}, {}) : null
```

Now If I want to access the id I can enter the following:

```
var NoData1Id = dataMapName['NoData1'].id
```

or

```
var NoData1Id = dataMapName.NoData1.id
```

However some of my data has spaces in the name such as:

```
data = [{ id: 99991, name: "NoData1", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99992, name: "NoData2", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99993, name: "NoData3", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99994, name: "NoData 4", title: "No Data" },
];
```

Is there a way that I could change my function so that it first removed spaces from the name during the reduction so that I could still enter:

```
var NoData4Id = dataMapName.NoData4.id
```

Comment: What does `: null` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then just replace space with an empty string.

```
var dataMapName = data.reduce((rv, v) => {
                     rv[v.name.replace(' ', '')] = v;
                     return rv;
                  }, {}) : null
```

and other option is to use the data as is, just make sure to use bracket notation.

```
var NoData4Id = dataMapName.["NoData 4"].id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to remove all spaces from name.

`\s` will match all the space characters like tabs, spaces, etc. `g` flag is for matching all the spaces.

```
rv[v.name.replace(/\s/g, '')] = v;
```

[**Demo**](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iemnz708/)

Comment: I'd use `/\s+/g` should there ever be two spaces in there instead of one.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand g flag removes all no matter what

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand Please read the last line of the question again

Comment: Yeah [this post has been edited] came up as I was typing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change key of the map while you are inserting:

```
data = [{ id: 99991, name: "NoData1", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99992, name: "NoData 2", title: "No Data" },
        { id: 99993, name: "NoData3", title: "No Data" }];

var dataMapName = data.reduce((rv, v) => {
                     var vName = v.name.replace(/\s/g,'');
                     rv[vName] = v;
                     return rv;
                  }, {}) : null
```